# Calculation of an integral with sign function

Tags: integration

I'm reading [this article](http://philoscience.unibe.ch/documents/TexteHS10/bell1964epr.pdf) (`J. S. Bell, On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen paradox, Physics 1, 195, 1964`) and I'm stuck at demonstrate the result (10).

Here is a summary of the problem :

- We are working in two dimensions (I think...)
- $\vec{\lambda}$ is a unit vector with uniform probability distribution over all directions
- $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are some unit vectors and $\theta$ is the angle between them

I try to calculate $P(\vec{a},\vec{b})$ which expression is given by
$$ P(\vec{a},\vec{b}) = \int \mathrm{d}\vec{\lambda}\; \rho(\vec{\lambda}) A(\vec{a},\vec{\lambda})B(\vec{b},\vec{\lambda})$$
and where $A(\vec{a},\lambda)$ and $B(\vec{b},\lambda)$ are given by
$$ A(\vec{a},\vec{\lambda}) = sign\;\vec{a}.\vec{\lambda} \\
B(\vec{b},\vec{\lambda}) = -sign\;\vec{b}.\vec{\lambda} $$
$sign\; x$ being $1$ if $x>0$, $0$ if $x=0$ and $-1$ if $x<0$.

I began by saying that $\vec{\lambda}$ is the reference vector and that the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{\lambda}$ is $\theta_1$. Then we have
$$ sign\;(\vec{a}.\vec{\lambda}).sign\;(\vec{b}.\vec{\lambda}) = sign\;(\cos(\theta_1)).sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta))$$

$$\begin{align}
P(\vec{a},\vec{b}) &= \int \mathrm{d}\vec{\lambda}\; \rho(\vec{\lambda}) A(\vec{a},\vec{\lambda})B(\vec{b},\vec{\lambda}) \\
                   &= - \int \mathrm{d}\theta_1 \;sign\;(\cos(\theta_1)).sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta))
\end{align}$$

I can then split the integral in two parts depending on the sign of $\cos\,\theta_1$

$$\begin{align}
P(\vec{a},\vec{b}) &= - \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 \;sign\;(\cos(\theta_1)).sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta)) \\
                   &= - \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 \;sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta)) + \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 \;sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta))
\end{align}$$

But here I'm a little bit stuck... Can I say that since $\cos(\theta_1+\theta)>0$ when $-\pi/2<\theta_1+\theta<\pi/2$, we have :

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 \;sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta)) 
    &= \int_{-\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2-\theta} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 - \int_{-\pi/2-\theta}^{-\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 +\left[- \int_{\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1\right]
\end{align}$$

Similarly, can I say that since $\cos(\theta_1+\theta)<0$ when $\pi/2<\theta_1+\theta<3\pi/2$, we have :

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 \;sign\;(\cos(\theta_1+\theta)) 
    &= \int_{\pi/2-\theta}^{3\pi/2-\theta} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 - \int_{\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1 +\left[- \int_{3\pi/2-\theta}^{3\pi/2} \mathrm{d}\theta_1\right]
\end{align}$$

Isn't it a bit weird ?

Comment: The result should be something like $-2\pi + 4\theta$ but I find 0...

Comment: A priori, $0\leqslant\theta\leqslant\pi$. Due to periodicity with period $\pi$, $P$ is a normalized integral over $\theta_1$ in $(0,\pi)$. "Normalized" means one must divide the integral by $\pi$ (which you forgot). Separating the cases $\theta\lt\pi/2$ and $\theta\gt\pi/2$, one can split $(0,\pi)$ into three subintervals where the sign is constant, either $+1$ or $-1$. Hence all that counts is the lengthes of these subintervals. In the end $P=(2\theta/\pi)-1$.

Comment: What is $\rho(\vec\lambda)$? In later formulas it disappears.

Comment: It's the probability distribution. But since it's uniform...

Answer (score 1):

Formula $(10)$ in the quoted paper is immediately obvious when you draw a little figure:

[image]

For $\theta<{\pi\over2}$ the figure is similar. The lengths of the blue arcs are $\pi-\theta$ each and the lengths of the red arcs are $\theta$ each. It follows that
$$P({\bf a},{\bf b})={1\over2\pi}\bigl(2(\pi-\theta)\cdot(-1)+2\theta\cdot1\bigr)=-1+{2\theta\over\pi}\ ,$$
as stated in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you give can be obtained at least in the case $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, I suspect it should not be difficult to do it for the remaining values in a similar fashion.
Divide up the region of integration $[0, 2\pi]$ according to the flip of sign for each part of the argument $A$ and $B$. I did the integration slightly different: let the vector $a$ be oriented along the $x$ axis and $\varphi$ be the angle between $\lambda$ and $a$, so that the angle between $\lambda$ and $b$ will be $\varphi - \theta$, then we must compute:

\begin{equation} 
-\int_{0}^{2 \pi} d \varphi ~sign(\cos \varphi) sign \cos(\varphi -\theta) \quad\quad\quad (1)
\end{equation}

To this end notice that the flips occur, for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, in $A$ so that $A \geq 0$ for $0 \leq \varphi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, $A \leq 0$ for $ \frac{\pi}{2} \leq \varphi \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$ and again $A \geq 0$ for $\frac{3\pi}{2} \leq \varphi \leq 2\pi$ and for $B$ so that $B \geq 0$ for $0 \leq \varphi \leq \frac{\pi}{2} + \theta$
and $B \leq 0$ for $ \frac{\pi}{2} + \theta \leq \varphi \leq \frac{3\pi}{2} + \theta $ and $B \geq 0$ when $ \frac{3\pi}{2} +\theta \leq \varphi \leq 2\pi$. Taking this into account (1) is

$$
-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d \varphi + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2} +\theta} d \varphi - \int_{\frac{\pi}{2} +\theta}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} d \varphi + \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}+ \theta} d \varphi - \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}+\theta}^{2\pi} d \varphi
 = -2\pi +4 \theta$$
Which is the result that should be.